# JBoss EAP 6.4 - Retrieve crl from distribution point using ca-revocation-url

Tags: ssl, jboss, wildfly, redhat

In trying to setup mutual authentication in JBoss EAP 6.4, we cannot get JBoss to pull a crl from a distribution point as defined by the ca-revocation-url property on the connector ssl definition. We are testing just using Google's crl distribution point listed on their certificate:

```
ca-revocation-url="http://crls.pki.goog/gts1c3/fVJxbV-Ktmk.crl"
```

but when we start JBoss, it throws the following error:

```
Error initializing endpoint: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\crls.pki.goog\gts1c3\fVJxbV-Ktmk.crl (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Does JBoss EAP 6.4 support the retrieval of crl files from distribution points and if so, do we need to encode the url so JBoss reads it properly?

Thanks